# Why socket.io removes properties that are equal to undefined

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to send request using `socket.io-client`:

```
socket.emit('eventName', {
  name: 'john doe',
  phone: undefined,
})
```

The problem is that server side `socket.io` receives this:

```
socket.on('eventName', obj => {
  console.log(obj) // {name: 'john doe'}
})
```

All the properties that are equal to undefined are get erased somewhere.

Comment: Probably because that's what `JSON.stringify` does.

Answer (score 1):

The data format for socket.io is JSON and the [JSON format specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) does not include `undefined` values.

A JSON value can be an `object`, `array`, `number`, `string`, `true`, `false`, or `null`.

So, when socket.io internally calls `JSON.stringify()`, it skips any properties that don't have one of these valid values.

This is how [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) describes the behavior of `JSON.stringify()`:

> If undefined, a function, or a symbol is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array). JSON.stringify can also just return undefined when passing in "pure" values like JSON.stringify(function(){}) or JSON.stringify(undefined).

So, you need to set the value of any property you want to send to one of these valid values.  In this particular case, you can set it to `null` or to an empty string.

Comment: @stkvtflw - Does this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to send empty data dont use undefined it means you erase that data instead use this:

```
socket.emit('eventName', {
  name: 'john doe',
  phone: '',
})
```

that way phone is still declared but not undefined and empty